# SQL - sum operations within case when statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum, case

I need to aggregate some sessions by day, country etc. The table has a transaction amount for each session (in local currency) and a field with the exchange_rate to EUR for the time of the transaction. Like this:

```
amount | currency | exchange_rate | date | country
```

I ran sum(amount/exchange_rate), however, for roughly 0.5% of the rows the value for exchange_rate is 0 and therefore it throws the error "cannot divide by 0".

I tried to run it with case when:

```
sum(case when exchange_rate = 0 then sum(amount) else sum(amount/exchange_rate) end) as volume
```

But apparently nested sum's are not allowed. Does anybody have an idea as to how I can get the result the above should logically produce, but without nested sums in a case when statement?

Comment: What do you want to do when the exchange rate is zero?

Comment: @The Impaler; I want to replace the 0 with 1, as GMB suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that an exchange rate of `0` indicates that the amount is in `EUR` currency already, you can do:

```
sum(amount / case when exchange_rate = 0 then 1 else exchange_rate end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
sum(case when exchange_rate = 0 then amount else amount/exchange_rate end) as volume
```

Or for a bit less typing:

```
sum(amount / coalesce(nullif(exchange_rate, 0), 1)) as volume
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to consider the exchange rate as `1` when it's zero. You can do:

```
sum(case when exchange_rate = 0 
         then amount 
         else amount/exchange_rate 
    end
) as volume
```